# CI project error in baseurl() after uploading the project at 000webhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I developed project with codeigniter and this code works fine on localhost.

```
 This user aleardy  founded.</p>
    <p> <a href="<?php  $id=8; echo base_url('log_c/login/' .$id);?> ">Log in</a> with it or <a href="<?php  $id=5; echo base_url('log_c/Signup/' .$id);?>">Sign up</a> with another user name<br><br>
```

And after uploading it on 000webhost .

**

- I write site_url  instead of base_url and get this error

**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect() [mysqli.real-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 161

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\application\models\login_m.php
Line: 7
Function: database

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\application\controllers\Log_c.php
Line: 12
Function: model

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 323
```

how to edit mysqlidriver.php?

Comment: Did you use  .htaccess file ..?

Comment: yes and all links work fine on server but this link no

Comment: `Log_c` in your controller. make sure your file name is `Log_c` where `L` should be in caps.

Comment: try change `base_url()` with `site_url()`

Comment: @AzharNabil 000webhost provide `hostname`, `username` and `password`. change your database configuration also in `database.php`.

Comment: I already changed  hostname,username,password  and database.is there any other file to change it?

Comment: No need to do anything else. see error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`. still it is working with username `root` and host `localhost`.

Comment: I found file in .idea folder is still with the name of localhost project helloworld.iml   how to deal with it? is this is the reason of error?

Comment: @AzharNabil see you are showing error of localhost. your error is showing `location` `C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\application\models\login_m.php`.

Comment: the error is still. I was changed database.php before upload it to 000webhost

Comment: It works  .i found another file localhost in it instead of host.thanks alot

Comment: @AzharNabil thats good, should be careful about file path when you work on server and localhost.